# How to return a 2D Array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Can someone help me how to pass the 2D array on main function? I searched a lot on web how to return an array but pointers didnt helped me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char fillcards(void)
{
    int i,j;
    srand(8490);
    char P[1001][16];
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
            char randomletter="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand() % 36];
            P[i][j]=randomletter;     
        }
    }                

    return P;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    ... // char P[.][.]=fillcards 
    printf("%s\n", P[1]); // Just to test

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't return arrays in C. You can return references to them. What I would suggest you do is perhaps allocate memory inside your fillcards() function using malloc or allocate memory in your main and pass a pointer to the allocated memory to fillcards().

Comment: Use a structure. C doesn't really have 2D arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems: The fists is that you tell the compiler the function should return a single character, but then return an array of arrays.

The second problem is that you attempt to return a local variable, a variable which will disappear as soon as the function returns.

The solution to the first issue depends on the solution you pick for the second issue. And the solution to the second issue is to either make sure the returned variable doesn't disappear by making it `static`, or by using dynamic memory allocations to create the memory for it.

If you you go for making the array `static` you have to remember that arrays decays to pointers to their first elements, and so once `P` has decayed you have something which is of the type `char (*)[16]`.

If you use dynamic memory allocation it kind of depends on what you declare `P` as, but most common is to use a pointer to a pointer, i.e. `char **`, which is then what you should use as return type.

Comment: I am still having syntax/compile errors can you post the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory. This is one solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** fillcards(void){
     int i,j,r=1001,c=16;
     srand(8490);


    char **P = (char **)malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         P[i] = (char *)malloc(c * sizeof(char));


     for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
                     {
                     for(j=0;j<15;j++){
                    char randomletter="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand() % 36];
                    P[i][j]=randomletter;
                    }
                    }

             return P;       
     }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

  char **A=fillcards();

   printf("%s\n", A[999]); // Just to test

 system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```